# How can I pass an id from js to rails when using ajax?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, routes

How can I call a rail route and pass in an ID from js.

I am switching to using rails routes through my application including in js

I have a call:

```
# app/assets/javascript/verifying_link.js
$.ajax({
  url: "/verify_link/"+id+"&table_row="+row,
```

but I want to use

```
# app/assets/javascript/verifying_link.js.erb
```

but how can I pass the id from js ?

I tried:

```
url: "<%= Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.verify_link_path(id) %>" + "&table_row="+row,
```

but I get an error:-

```
undefined local variable or method `id' for#<#<Class:0x00000001ca3220>:0x007f6228c792f0>
(in /...linker/app/assets/javascript/verifying_link.js.erb)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. Insert it into the link
> 2. Pass it as data

--

**Route**

As you've attempted already, you could pass it in the route itself:

```
# app/assets/javascript/verifying_link.js
$(document).on("click", ".element", function(){
   $.ajax({
     url: "/verify_link/"+id+"&table_row="+row
   });
});
```

The way to do this is to include the `id` from your HTML.

Your `ajax` will no doubt be triggered by an event. The event will correspond to an HTML element, which can now have `data`, or `id` attributes (thanks to [HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)):

```
#app/views/controller/view.html.erb
<%= link_to "Your Link", path_to_link, id: @item.id %>

#app/assets/javascript/verifying_link.js
$(document).on("click", ".element", function(){
   var id = $(this).attr("id");

   $.ajax({
      url: "/verify_link/"+id,
   });
});
```

You'd need to make sure you pass the data to JS from **HTML** to make this work

---

**Data**

Alternatively (and this will only work on `collection` routes), you could send the `id` in the data tag. Of course, this will not do anything to help you include your `id` in your JS, but it's still very important:

```
#app/assets/javascript/verifying_link.js
$(document).on("click", ".element", function(){
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   $.ajax({
      url: "/verify_link",
      data: { id: id }
   });
});
```

The difference here is that if you wanted include other data, you could include it in the `data` attribute. Further, you'll want to make sure that your routes correspond to what you're looking to send as data (IE `member` routes will need to have the `id` appended to the URL)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access to Rails values direct in js files. You can pass value in url or create hidden block in you view. Then you can read these values.